# Entity Model or Pojo Class as a return object of REST API

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, spring-boot, jpa

I am working with REST API, 
Is there any wrong if given the list of  Model Class Objects as response directly to the user.
or should I need to map those Actual Model class to any POJA class before Returning?

eg : 
if the API is forgetting all Users ("/Users")

then is it a good coding method to return directly

```
return userRepository.findAll();
```

or need to convert it to any `List<UserPOJO>` before returning?

Or is there any good codding standards?

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, it is usually better to map the Entities to equivalent POJO classes.

Here are a few reasons:

**1)** Most of the time you do not need all the data that is stored in an entity. You can map only the subset that is needed in the response.

**2)** From a security perspective, it is always good to have some sort of a middle ground where you filter out the sensitive data that should not actually put in the response. Or only for certain users which you can decide during the mapping.

**3)** Hibernate objects are not plain objects, they are proxies. This may cause unnecessary lazy loading for example of `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToMany` relations. You should be able to control that and from my experience, Jackson loads all things possible, unless you annotate it with a `@JsonIgnore`.

Unless you are working with a very simple and not security-heavy app, then I would stay with Hibernate objects. But otherwise, which is most cases, I would go for the mapping.